# How can i find two extra characters in DB2 and list down those in a column?

Tags: sql, regex, count, db2, extract

I have written this expression for checking extra characters and I am counting the occurrence of those extra characters.

```
REGEXP_COUNT('Mr.John® Êlite', regexp_extract ('Mr.John® Êlite','[^\x00-\x7F]'))
```

It's working fine if the string has only one extra character e.g 
Mr. John® 
It will take out ®  and give me count as 1.
But if my string has two extra characters, it will only pick the first one and ignore the second character e.g

Mr.John® Êlite

My function will extract  ® and ignore Ê.
I have tried subquery as well.Not working.Need help

Comment: Maybe all you need is `REGEXP_COUNT('Mr.John® Êlite', '[^\x00-\x7F]')`?

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Wiktor Stribiżew [`REGEXP_COUNT`](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061491.html?pos=2) needs just a source string and regexp:

```
 db2 "values REGEXP_COUNT('Mr.John® Êlite', '[^\x00-\x7F]')"

1          
-----------
          2
```

Because you used [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061492.html?pos=2), it does extract the first occurrence only:

> The REGEXP_EXTRACT scalar function returns one occurrence of a substring of a string that matches the regular expression pattern.

and only then you do actual count.